# Local DNS forwarder for Windows

Tags: windows, dns

I have an internal network of computers that I access from my laptop via a VPN.

I would like to run a local DNS forwarder on the laptop, so that I can forward DNS requests that relate to that network to a server on the VPN, but handle other requests "normally" by forwarding to a standard Internet DNS resolver.

Requirements:

- Runs on Windows 7
- Should be able to forward to different servers based on the domain being looked up
- Capable of being accessed remotely (actually just by virtual machines running on the laptop)
- Ideally would pick up the servers allocated by DHCP on each interface so it uses the ISP's  DNS server no matter which ISP I am connected to, but I could probably just use `8.8.8.8` if this isn't feasible
- Preferably quite lightweight - i.e. easy to install and configure

Comment: May I introduce you to the The [Name Resolution Policy Table](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ff394369.aspx).  It is a PITA to use, but it is builtin.  The only thing I am not sure about is if this available in the home edition.  I know it is in Pro/Enterprise.

Comment: Thanks, I've got Pro. It presumably doesn't satisfy the "accessed remotely" requirement but I might be able to manage the VMs differently.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[WinGate](http://www.wingate.com) will do all of this.

By default its internal DNS client uses the local host environment's DNS servers, but you can also add DNS servers to be used per domain.

DNS is free as well in terms of licensing, so the free 10 user license will do this.

Disclaimer: I work for Qbik who are the authors of WinGate.